# create a Dynamic mapping for parsing multiple input files to an obj in kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

Let's say I have a json data that can have different Key names for the same data field

Json type A

> {
>     "width": 1024,
>     "height": 768,
>     "color": "#ff0000"
>   }

also there is a mapping json that give me what attirbute should map with what in the data class 
 Json type A

> {
>     "width": w,
>     "height": h,
>     "color": "Color"
>   }

Json Type B

> {
>     "widthOfobj": 1024,
>     "heightOfobj": 768,
>     "colorOfobj": "#ff0000"
>   }

Json Type mapping document B

> {
>     "widthOfobj": w,
>     "heightOfobj": h,
>     "colorOfobj": "Color"
>   }

in my kotlin data class I have obj defined as

```
data class dimension(W: int, H: int, Color: String)
```

now I want to map either of json type A or B to the kotlin data class with help of reading the mapping document. How would i go about doing something like that?

here is the flow I am thinking about for clarity purpose

sudo code

```
 Data class dimension( W: int, H: int, Color:String)// already defined
//Read mapping document to map 
    val Map = readmappingfile(mappingfile)  //e. g  Width to W
                                      //      Height to H
Val input Data= readJson(input) //      { "width": 1024, "height": 768, "color": "#ff0000" }
Val show result = applytransformation( mappingfile, input)
// inside applytransformation Read the Map and data and serialize it to data class  
//oneway of just serializing  it would be using gson 
val result = gson.fromJson(input,dimension::class.java) // this would work if input was in format ( w->v , h-> v , Color->v)
```

// how do i make that change to convert weight to W before I call gson code above to serialize it to data class.  Note it needs to be dynamic enough so we don't Write up a hard coded mapping.

Comment: If you're using Gson you can annotate your property with: `@SerializedName("color", alternate = {"colorOfobj"})`. This will deserialise both types and serialise using "type A" only (just swap the 2 values if you prefer to serialise "type B" instead). If you're using other JSON libraries you may need to implement the deserialiser by yourself

Comment: I am trying to not write custom serializer this I want to able to make mapping based on the second file. this way i can remove hard coding from the code.  as such that if the input columns change tomorrow i do not need to go into the code to make the changes just update the mapping file and it should be able to handle any structure changes. as in change in names.

Answer (score 0):

I think of you to use custom deserializer for gson.

check this [example](https://medium.com/@int02h/custom-deserialization-with-gson-1bab538c0bfa).

Comment: Choim,  This is not what I was exactly looking for I can implement this but at the end of the day the code is still written in the shapes abstract class implementation.  the question here is how can use the second json and get the mapping at runtime instead of writing the code at compile time.

Comment: @user2315840 you don't need to write shape abstract class. you just write `Dimension` deserializer and override `deserialize` method. And then, load second json object and try to map with first json object. if mapped correctly, you would create dimension instance your self in the `deserialize` method.